# Does git pull replace everything in my local repository?

Tags: git, git-pull

Let's say I have a server side and a client side directory. I've made changes on the client side with things like themes. If I `git pull` will it replace everything on both directories?

Comment: Why would `pull`ing from the server modify anything on the server?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWYnQ.png

Answer (score 1):

No it does not. It will attempt to incorporate changes from the remote repository into the branch. It won’t overwrite local files that it’s not touching and it will notify you if there are issues with the pull. Additionally, a simple `git pull` will not have any impact on your remote repository.

`git reset --hard <whatever>` on the other hand will overwrite local files and a `git push <whatever>` may have an effect on your remote.